# How to add objects to a std::vector<unique_ptr<obj>>?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unique-ptr, raii

**Question:**
*How to add objects to a `std::vector<unique_ptr<obj>>`?* 
I have a class, and this is what I am **trying** to do...
Below, I'm trying to use `std::unique_ptr<Ball>` in my vector, as I thought it would be the easiest.

```
class Ball {
public:
    Ball(float x, float y);
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Ball>> object;
    // other declarations below...
};
```

Here I am trying to *push_back* new elements:

```
Ball ball { 0, 0 };
for (size_t i { 0 }; i != 50; ++i) {
ball.object.push_back(new Ball { 0, 0 });
//        ^ here is the error
}
```

And I do no understand the error I'm getting.
**Error:**
`error C2664: 'void std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Ball,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>::push_back(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'Ball *' to 'std::unique_ptr<Ball,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &&'`

Comment: A Ball owns a bunch of Balls? That's an odd design.

Comment: Use `emplace_back` to pass the arguments to `unique_ptr`'s constructor.

Comment: `unique_ptr`'s converting constructor, that takes ownership of a raw pointer, [is marked `explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr). Therefore, you have to *explicitly* perform the conversion from raw pointer to `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @dyp Technically speaking, it's not an converting constructor if it's explicit :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `push_back`, you need to create a `unique_ptr`. Since that's too much typing and error-prone, you can use `emplace_back` instead to forward your ball object. In C++14, `make_unique` is available and should be preferred.

```
for (size_t i { 0 }; i != 50; ++i) {
    ball.balls.emplace_back(new Ball { 0, 0 });
}
```

Comment: Your solution is also error-prone, if `emplace_back` tries to reallocate the vector and fails it will not delete the pointer. You should still create a temporary `unique_ptr` even when using `emplace_back`

Answer (score 3):

If you use a `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` there is no need to explicitly release memory because it will automatically released when calling the destructor of the enclosing class.

You must create a `unique_ptr<Ball>` object, you can't pass directly a `Ball*`. Best solution is to use `std::make_unique<Ball>(0,0)`.

Comment: That's for C++14, though.

Comment: Question title didn't match body, and you answered the title.  Now the title has been changed to match the body, and your question doesn't answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you are looking for the simplest thing to do,  use a `std::vector<Ball>` instead of a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Ball>>`.  No need to add in the complexity of pointer ownership.

Comment: That's technically UB since `std::vector` isn't guaranteed to support incomplete types...yet.